# Sharepoint/Project Server 2013 Walkthrough: Create a SharePoint-hosted Project Server app

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-project-server-2013

when I follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj873844.aspx and publish (with F5) my app and function is called:

```
function getAssignments() {
    assignments = PS.EnterpriseResource.getSelf(projContext).get_assignments();

    projContext.load(assignments,
        'Include(Project, Name, ActualWork, ActualWorkMilliseconds, PercentComplete, RemainingWork, Finish, Task)');

    // Run the request on the server.
    projContext.executeQueryAsync(onGetAssignmentsSuccess,
        // Anonymous function to execute if getAssignments fails.
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to get assignments. Error: ' + args.get_message());
        });
}
```

I get following error:

Error: GeneralSecurityAccessDenied

Do you have any idea why? Everywhere I am using my local account that belongs to administrator group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the article up to the end?

There is an AppManifest.xml sample, and it contains 2 permissions:

```
   <AppPermissionRequests>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver/statusing" Right="SubmitStatus" />
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver/projects" Right="Read" />
   </AppPermissionRequests>
```

If u dont give those permissions to the app, it cant get data from project server and give you Error: GeneralSecurityAccessDenied